# TypeError: 'classname' object is not callable (inside a method called via tkinter.Button.command)

Tags: python, tkinter

i would like to call a method of an object when clicking a tkinter.Button.

I have reduced my code to the code below. When i call the function (newone) directly (as in "newone('three')"), everything seems fine, but when the button gets clicked (which calls the same function) i get an error.

I looked at similar posts on 'typerror: x is ont callable' but i did not find anything similar to my code and i have no idea what is going wrong here. The actual call to lot.addone(name) seems to work since i only get the error when i want to instantiate a new object inside addone(). Is the class thing() no longer visible (due to calling it via a tkinter.button?) and how can i make it visible again? Any help would be appreciated.

```py
    import tkinter

    window = tkinter.Tk()

    def newone(name='four'):
        global lot
        lot.addone(name)

    class thing:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = 'nothing'

    class list_of_things:
        def __init__(self):
            self.things = dict()

        def addone(self, name):
            self.things[name] = thing()     ## the error location
            self.things[name].name = name


    lot = list_of_things()
    lot.addone('one')   ## something dummy
    lot.addone('two')
    newone('three')     ## this works

    print(lot.things['one'].name)
    print(lot.things['three'].name)   ## prints out correctly

    row_index = 0
    for (key, thing) in lot.things.items():
        tkinter.Label(window, text = thing.name).grid(row = row_index)
        row_index = row_index + 1

    tkinter.Button(window, text = 'New task', command = newone).grid(row = row_index) ## this fails

    window.mainloop()
```

the error i am getting is the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\tools\Miniconda3\envs\3dot6kivy\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 8, in newone
    lot.addone(name)
  File "test.py", line 19, in addone
    self.things[name] = thing()     ## the error location
TypeError: 'thing' object is not callable
```

Comment: `thing` is not what you think it is. You've used the same name for a variable and for a class. Using pep8 standards will help avoid this specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class name `thing` was masked by a variable named `thing`. I renamed the class to `Thing`, and it worked.

Other adjustments were also made in the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        print("adding a 'Thing' object")
        self.name = 'nothing'


class ListOfThings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.things = dict()

    def addone(self, name):
        self.things[name] = Thing()
        self.things[name].name = name


def newone(name='four'):
    lot.addone(name)       # lot doesn't need to be global if you are not assigning to it


if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = tk.Tk()

    lot = ListOfThings()
    lot.addone('one')
    lot.addone('two')
    newone('three')

    print(lot.things['one'].name)
    print(lot.things['three'].name)

    row_index = 0
    for (key, thing) in lot.things.items():
        tk.Label(window, text=thing.name).grid(row=row_index)
        row_index = row_index + 1

    tk.Button(window, text='New task', command=newone).grid(row=row_index)

    window.mainloop()
```